# Difference between "did broke" vs. "was broken" vs. "broken"?

Tags: tense, past-tense

> How **did** the window **broke**?
>
> How **was** the window **broken**?
>
> How the window **broken**?

Do all the above sentences mean same meaning?

Which one is more common?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you copied the questions incorrectly from your book when you wrote them here to ask this question. You should look back at your source because I don't think a grammar book would have constructions one and three since they are impossible to say under the rules of English grammar.

Comment: Actually, first sentence was a stupid mistake by me. I know that there should be "break" instead of "broke". Second one is from the book. Third one, i just made it to know is it ok to say that simple in informal speech.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I want to start off saying that only the second example is an English question; the other examples you've listed are written using poor English grammar:

> How did the window broke? (Not possible; terrible grammar)
>
> How was the window broken?
>
> How the window broken? (Not possible; terrible grammar)

What you meant to write for the first example is this:

> How **did** the window **BREAK**?

For the third example, I think you meant to write:

> How **did** the window **get broken**?
>
> or
>
> How **did** the window **become broken**?

Now to answer your question: after I have corrected the sentences so that they make sense grammatically, all three of your examples mean the same thing.  As for which one is said more often, I can only guess as I have no evidence to prove this, but I would say that your first example, after being corrected by me so that it be grammatical, is probably the most common of the three examples:

> How **did** the window **break**?

I hope that might have helped you out.  Take care and good luck.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, first sentence was a stupid mistake by me. Anyhow thanks for pointing that. Does this mean same meaning? "How did the window break?" "How was the window broken?"

Comment: Yes, the former is in the active voice and the second is in the passive voice.

Answer (score 1):

The first and third sentences are ungrammatical, so we could say they have no meaning, and are both less common than the correct one, "How was the window broken?"